# Не работает hoover

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при наведении на любую картинку у меня появлялся на ней специальный блок, но он отказывается появляться.

Что сделано не так?

```css
.tab-content{
    position:relative;
}
.product-content-hover{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:270px;
    height:270px;
    outline: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-hover{
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.35);
    font-size: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.fishnet-chair{
    color: #212121;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:700px;
}
.details{
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 206px;
    height: 33px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
}
.img-product{
    padding-right:15px;
}
.img-product:last-child{
    padding-right:0;
}
.img-product:hover .product-content-hover{
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="product-content-hover">
        <a href="#" class="icon-hover">></a>
        <p class="fishnet-chair">Fishnet Chair</p>
        <p class="details">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam
. Steel frame, available in matt powder-coated black
 or highly polished chrome.</p>
        </div>
    <img src="Images/product-1.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
    <img src="Images/product-2.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
    <img src="Images/product-3.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
    <img src="Images/product-4.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переместив блок `.product-content-hover` вниз Вы сможете воспользоваться [~ селектором](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), который позволит манипулировать им в случае события `hover` на элементе `.img-product`:

```css
.tab-content {
  position: relative;
}

.product-content-hover {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  outline: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.icon-hover {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.35);
  font-size: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.fishnet-chair {
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700px;
}

.details {
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 206px;
  height: 33px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #6c6c6c;
}

.img-product {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.img-product:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.img-product:hover ~ .product-content-hover {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <img src="Images/product-1.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
  <img src="Images/product-2.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
  <img src="Images/product-3.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
  <img src="Images/product-4.jpg" class="img-product"></img>
  <div class="product-content-hover">
    <a href="#" class="icon-hover">></a>
    <p class="fishnet-chair">Fishnet Chair</p>
    <p class="details">Seat and back with upholstery made of cold cure foam . Steel frame, available in matt powder-coated black or highly polished chrome.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как понять "переместив блок .product-content-hover вниз"? Сделал, как Вы написали - не заработало)) значит что-то не то я сделал)

Comment: Уже разобрался, спасибо. Но блок просто ниже появляется, а не на каждой наведённой картинке. Чтобы работало при активации или наведении на каждую картинку нудно к каждому div'у картинки расписать реакцию?

Comment: В моем примере реализовано только то что у Вас было указано в вопросе. У вас один блок информации и 4 картинки. По наведению на каждую из них появляется блок с информацией (один и тот же). Если вы хотите что бы это стилистически выглядело по другому, то это решается изменением стилей. Если для каждого изображения блок с информацией должен быть свой то скомпонуйте доп. информацию и изображение так что бы получался один логический блок.

Comment: Именно по-этому отметил Ваш ответ, как решением моего вопроса. Буду разбираться. Спасибо, за помощь.